# How to merge later commit from a branch into master discarding some earlier changes?

Tags: git

Sorry I am a newbie in git/github, even I do not know how to use correct words for those questions so I drew some diagram instead.

In branch dev I have two commits, one is the change to file a.py (commit 2), the other one is the change to file b.py (commit 3).

My first question is now I want my master, at the future commit 4, has the features that the file b.py from commit 3 has, but not the changed a.py. How to do it with git?

My second question is, just assume the owner of the repository in github is A, and then I forked/cloned the repository from the commit 1 and created the dev branch myself with the two commits 2 and 3 as described. A has already had some commits in the meanwhile, says 1' and 1''. Now I want to contribute my change for file b.py but not a.py to the master branch. How do I do this. I know it must be something with pull request but I haven't figured it out.

I will be appreciated with concrete answers for both questions, but some pointers to the appropriate section of some free git course/book are also much appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE:

My bad that I named the other branch "dev" here, in fact this is a "feature" branch, and that feature is enabled by the change on file a.py on commit 2. So until I am able to somehow make a kind of combination in the code of file a.py to cover both cases, the master is a software and the "dev"/"feature" branch will be another software.

But the change on file b.py with the commit 3 is good for both branches/softwares. The problem is that, if I has changed the file b.py before the file a.py in the "dev"/"feature" branch, it would have been no problem at all. In that case, I could merge the change on file b.py to the master, and continue developing the feature branch by changing file a.py. I know the current situation is not so good, but both changes are not mistake and I don't want to get rid of them.

My (theoretical) solution:

- Create another branch from commit 1, says "improved", patch the diff of file b.py, merge it to master, says, at commit 4.
- Then create another branch named "feature A" from commit 4, patch the diff of file a.py and let it runs along its own.

Is it a sensible way to go?

[image: GIT Question]

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on why you made this branch (`dev`). What's the goal here? If this is a feature branch and you made commit 2 and 3 and you just want to throw away commit 2 (it was a total mistake), that is a possible thing to do. Now no one will ever acquire it.

But if you *don't* want to throw away commit 2, but you don't want `master` or a PR to have it, then the question is, what is this branch for anyway? It seems to me that in that case this is just the wrong branch. You should make a *different* branch that has 3 but not 2, if you are going to be merging 3 but not 2 into things.

In other words, if you've got things to contribute for file b only, then you need a branch for the changes on file b only.

So what I would do is completely reorganize these branches. I would divide my changes into the branch that affects file a and another branch that affects file b. Now you can merge the branch that affects file b to master, or send it as a PR, or whatever.

Then, locally, you can merge the file-b branch into the file-a branch. Now *you* and you alone have both sets of commits and you can continue working on the file-a branch, which now also contains the file-b changes.

Comment: Yes, I do not want to throw away commit 2. I wrote an update on the original post. Now the solution I can think of is to create another branch from commit 1, says "improved", patch the diff of file b.py, merge it to master, says, at commit 4, then I create another branch named "feature A" from commit 4, patch the diff of file a.py and let it runs along its own. Is it a sensible way to do?

Comment: I don't know, the use of patches seems overblown to me. I would just make a new branch starting at 1 and cherry pick 3 onto it, and merge. Now that branch is pointless so delete it, and keep working on your original branch.

Comment: No I still want to keep that branch, or at least the feature it owns (changes from commit 2 on the file a.py)

Comment: OK, cool, so keep it (after the merge). Or you can do this whole game again later. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have options.  I think the first question is if you want the changes in commit 2 at all, or if they were a mistake and you want to get rid of them.  If they were a mistake, then the simplest thing to do is "git revert" commit 2 on your `dev` branch.  Then `dev` will only have the commit 3 changes and you can then go on and merge that branch into wherever you wanted the commit 3 changes to go.

If you still want commit 2, and you just want to separate 2 and 3, then things are more complicated and what you do depends on what you want to have end up in your `dev` branch...just 2 or just 3.  If you want 3 to stay in `dev`, then do a branch off of 2 to create a new branch for it and then do the same thing I describe above...apply a revert of commit 2 to the `dev` branch.  If you want 2 in the `dev` branch and `3` somewhere else, then you probably want to cherry-pick 3 to wherever you want those changes to go, and then revert 3 from the `dev` branch so that it only contains commit 2.

Comment: It sounds reasonable but a little bit complicated to a git newbie like me. I updated the question, that I don't want to get rid of changes in commit 2. Between your solution and this solution, which one is better and git-ish way to do?

My (theoretical) solution:
- Create another branch from commit 1, says "improved", patch the diff of file b.py, merge it to master, says, at commit 4,
- Then create another branch named "feature A" from commit 4, patch the diff of file a.py and let it runs along its own.

Comment: Yes, that is a fine way to go.  I guess I was just trying to reuse your  existing commits and branches, but hey, they're cheap.  So yes, you can just reapply the changes from commits 2 and 3 separately to wherever you want to put them via a cherry-pick.  All a cherry-pick is is basically a simplified way of creating a patch from one or more commits in your tree and applying the changes somewhere else.  That's just fine...well except for one small complication...

Comment: ...what do you want to do with your `dev` branch?  With the way you've gone, you haven't affected it.  If you want to throw it away and create a `dev2` branch, then you're home free.  But if you want to keep using it, you've got a bit more work to do.  You still need to revert whichever of the commits you don't want in the `dev` branch moving forward.  That's no big deal though.  That's just one more Git command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use cherry-pick.

   `git log` - to find commit hash.

   `git cherry-pick "commit hash"` - apply changes of a specific commit.
2. Easiest way is create new brach from master and cherry-pick necessary commits from dev branch then make a Pull Request.

Comment: In case you don't know what cherry-picking does...There's no way to merge node 3 into master or any place else if you don't want to bring along 2.  What cherry-picking does is create a new commit from some set of changes that you made somewhere else.  In terms of the operation itself, it's the same as if you lost the changes you made in node 3 and had to type them in again by hand.  It just re-applies the changes and the commit messages as though you'd done them in the new location initially.